# Path for nodejs and npm is different

Tags: node.js, npm, ubuntu-14.04

I am using Ubuntu 14.04LTS

I am having nodejs(default package) at path **/usr/bin/nodejs**

I am having npm at path **/usr/local/bin/npm**

When I run npm -v It says

```
bash: /usr/local/bin/npm: /usr/local/bin/node: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

I tried installing the npm with the command below as

> $ sudo curl -L https://npmjs.org/install.sh | sh
>
> % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time 
>   Current
>                                    Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed 100   193  100   193    0     0    159      0  0:00:01  0:00:01
>   --:--:--   160 100  6711  100  6711    0     0   3028      0  0:00:02  0:00:02 --:--:--  8876 npm cannot be installed without nodejs. Install
>   node first, and then try again.
>
> Maybe node is installed, but not in the PATH? Note that running as
>   sudo can change envs.

What can be done in order to run npm here?

Comment: Did you try `$ apt-get install npm` ?

Comment: On doing this it says-->npm is already the newest version.

Comment: What `whereis npm` outputs?

Comment: `apt-get install nodejs` should already include `npm` (note "[Super Easy Install](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/README.html#super-easy-install)"). The `install.sh` shouldn't be necessary and using it probably reconfigured `npm`.

Comment: npm: /usr/bin/npm /usr/bin/X11/npm /usr/local/bin/npm /usr/share/npm /usr/share/man/man3/npm.3.gz /usr/share/man/man1/npm.1.gz

Comment: @JonathanLonowski what will be the best way to proceed now?

Comment: @Mozak Yeah you should try purging `nodejs` and `npm` all-together and follow the easy install guide that @Jonathan has provided.

Answer (score 0):

First remove your current nodejs and npm, then install with [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) (Node Version Manager).
To install:

```
$ curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.17.1/install.sh | bash
```

nvm is a version manager similar to `rvm`(ruby) and `gvm`(groovy)